# How to correctly implement a python iterator in C++?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, iterator, python-extensions

As a part of a Python module I'm writing in C++ I need to make a type containing an `std::vector` iterable in Python.

I added a `tp_iter` function to the type containing the `vector` that creates an iterator object which has a `tp_iternext`. The iterator contains copies of the `begin` and `end` iterators from the `vector`.

The test output shows that everything is fine inside the `foo_iter`'s constructor, but inside the `tp_iternext` function the `it` iterator points to a null pointer, even though the address of `it` itself hasn't changed!

Here is a sample code. This is just an example that reproduces the problem.
Sorry about the long listing. I'm just not sure where the bug is hiding.

```
#include <vector>

#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

#define STR1(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR1(x)

#include <iostream>
#define TEST(var) std::cout << \
  "\033[33m" STR(__LINE__) ": " \
  "\033[36m" #var ":\033[0m " << (var) << std::endl;

namespace {

template <typename T>
void tp_dealloc(T* self) noexcept {
  // self->~T();
  // Py_TYPE(self)->tp_free(self);
  auto tp = Py_TYPE(self);
  self->~T();
  tp->tp_free(self);
}

template <typename T>
PyObject* tp_new(PyTypeObject* subtype, PyObject* args, PyObject* kwargs)
noexcept {
  PyObject* obj = subtype->tp_alloc(subtype,0);
  new(reinterpret_cast<T*>(obj)) T(args,kwargs);
  return obj;
}

struct py_foo {
  PyObject_HEAD

  using vec_t = std::vector<PyObject*>;
  vec_t vec;

  py_foo(PyObject* args, PyObject* kwargs) noexcept
  : vec( PyTuple_GET_SIZE(args) )
  {
    for (size_t i=0; i<vec.size(); ++i)
      Py_INCREF(vec[i] = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(args,i));
  }

  ~py_foo() {
    for (PyObject* x : vec)
      Py_DECREF(x);
  }
};

struct py_foo_iter {
  PyObject_HEAD

  decltype(std::declval<py_foo::vec_t&>().begin()) it;
  decltype(std::declval<py_foo::vec_t&>().end  ()) end;

  py_foo_iter(PyObject* args, PyObject* kwargs) noexcept
  : py_foo_iter( reinterpret_cast<py_foo*>(PyTuple_GET_ITEM(args,0))->vec )
  { }

  py_foo_iter(py_foo::vec_t& v) noexcept: it(v.begin()), end(v.end()) {
    TEST(this)
    TEST(v[0])
    TEST(&(this->it))
    TEST(*this->it)
    TEST(Py_TYPE(v[0])->tp_name)
  }
};

struct foo_iter_py_type: PyTypeObject {
  foo_iter_py_type(): PyTypeObject{ PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(nullptr, 0) } {
    tp_name = "my.foo_iter";
    tp_basicsize = sizeof(py_foo_iter);
    tp_new = (::newfunc) ::tp_new<py_foo_iter>;
    tp_dealloc = (::destructor) ::tp_dealloc<py_foo_iter>;
    tp_iternext = (::iternextfunc) +[](py_foo_iter* self) noexcept
      -> PyObject* {
        TEST(self)
        TEST(Py_TYPE(self)->tp_name)
        TEST(&(self->it))
        TEST(*self->it)
        auto& it = self->it;
        if (it == self->end) return nullptr;
        PyObject* obj = *it;
        TEST(obj)
        ++it;
        Py_INCREF(obj);
        TEST(__FUNCTION__)
        TEST( Py_TYPE(obj)->tp_name )
        
        return obj;
      };
  }
} foo_iter_py_type;

struct foo_py_type: PyTypeObject {
  foo_py_type(): PyTypeObject{ PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(nullptr, 0) } {
    tp_name = "my.foo";
    tp_basicsize = sizeof(py_foo);
    tp_dealloc = (::destructor) ::tp_dealloc<py_foo>;
    tp_flags = Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT | Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE;
    tp_new = (::newfunc) ::tp_new<py_foo>;
    tp_iter = (::getiterfunc) +[](PyObject* self) noexcept {
      TEST(__FUNCTION__)
      PyObject* args = PyTuple_New(1);
      reinterpret_cast<PyTupleObject*>(args)->ob_item[0] = self;
      TEST(__FUNCTION__)
      PyObject* iter = PyObject_CallObject(
        reinterpret_cast<PyObject*>(&foo_iter_py_type), args );
      Py_DECREF(args);
      TEST(__FUNCTION__)
      TEST(reinterpret_cast<py_foo_iter*>(iter))
      TEST(*reinterpret_cast<py_foo_iter*>(iter)->it)
      return iter;
    };
  }
} foo_py_type;

struct py_module: PyModuleDef {
  py_module(): PyModuleDef{ PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT } {
    m_name = "my";
    m_doc = "test module";
    m_size = -1;
  }
} py_module;

}

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_my() {
  struct {
    PyTypeObject* type;
    const char* name;
  } static constexpr py_types[] {
    { &foo_py_type, "foo" },
    { &foo_iter_py_type, "foo_iter" }
  };

  for (auto [type, name] : py_types)
    if (PyType_Ready(type) < 0) return nullptr;

  PyObject* m = PyModule_Create(&py_module);
  if (!m) return nullptr;

  unsigned n = 0;
  for (auto [type, name] : py_types) {
    Py_INCREF(type);
    ++n;
    if (PyModule_AddObject(m, name, reinterpret_cast<PyObject*>(type)) < 0) {
      do {
        Py_DECREF(py_types[--n].type);
      } while (n);
      Py_DECREF(m);
      return nullptr;
    }
  }

  return m;
}
```

I'm testing this module with the following Python script:

```
import my

f = my.foo(1,'a',2,'b')

for x in f:
    print(x)
```

Here is the output:

```
105: __FUNCTION__: operator()
108: __FUNCTION__: operator()
63: this: 0x7fa78cbd1c50
64: v[0]: 0x7fa78ca69a60
65: &(this->it): 0x7fa78cbd1c60
66: *this->it: 0x7fa78ca69a60
67: Py_TYPE(v[0])->tp_name: int
112: __FUNCTION__: operator()
113: reinterpret_cast<py_foo_iter*>(iter): 0x7fa78cbd1c50
114: *reinterpret_cast<py_foo_iter*>(iter)->it: 0x7fa78ca69a60
79: self: 0x7fa78cbd1c50
80: Py_TYPE(self)->tp_name: my.foo_iter
81: &(self->it): 0x7fa78cbd1c60
82: *self->it: 0
86: obj: 0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: There's a lot of this that doesn't make sense. You're trying to access `Py_TYPE(self)` after you already called the destructor, you've got a vector in a type that needs to be standard-layout, and you're missing reference management in a bunch of places.

Comment: Thanks for catching the access of `Py_TYPE(self)` after the destructor. I've fixed that, but that was an unrelated problem. `std::vector` itself is a fixed-size object, so I don't understand why it cannot be used in a standard-layout python object.

Comment: I think I found the missing reference counting. It had to do with the references stored in the `vector`. Also wasn't the cause of the problem.

Comment: I don't think this is a matter of "the problem". Your code has lots of problems.

Comment: Could you, please, be more specific? I'm not purporting that this code doesn't work despite not having any problems ;)

Comment: You forgot to incref self when you did `reinterpret_cast<PyTupleObject*>(args)->ob_item[0] = self;` (and you should probably use [`PyTuple_SET_ITEM`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/tuple.html#c.PyTuple_SET_ITEM) to set that entry anyway, or build the tuple with `PyTuple_Pack`, or use `PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs`.)

Comment: You might want to try Cython or Boost.Python or some other library or tool that could make this easier.

Comment: This incref was it! I think I didn't incref here because I thought that this temporary tuple, which only serves to pass the argument to the `foo_iter`'s constructor, wasn't going to leave my code and wouldn't be seen by python's garbage collector.
Is there a way to pass a pointer to the `foo` instance to the `foo_iter`'s constructor without this intermediate tuple?

Comment: `PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs` would let you call the function without building an argument tuple manually.